# Django and Heroku: Static files work with 'foreman start' but not './manage.py runserver'

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

**I have added my own answer to the answers below, this has been solved.**

I am able to serve up static files when powering up the server using the heroku tool `foreman`:

```
$ foreman start
12:25:21 web.1  | started with pid 33574
12:25:21 web.1  | 2013-04-10 12:25:21 [33577] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.2
12:25:21 web.1  | 2013-04-10 12:25:21 [33577] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (33577)
12:25:21 web.1  | 2013-04-10 12:25:21 [33577] [INFO] Using worker: sync
12:25:21 web.1  | 2013-04-10 12:25:21 [33582] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33582
```

but they static files aren't served up using runserver:

```
$ ./manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
April 10, 2013 - 12:26:06
Django version 1.5, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

My `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

My `settings.py` (some settings removed):

```
import os
import logging

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

# Using local_settings for this
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Heroku specific database settings, overridden for local dev in local_settings.py (not in git)
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure() (also needed for Heroku)
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'stripe',
    'notification',
    'south',
    'registration',
    'timedelta',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'django_messages',
    'tinymce',
)

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

My main `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, handler500, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.root', name='root'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

As the title says I'm able to load all my static assets using `foreman start` but not when running `./manage.py runserver`.

I've also ran `./manage.py collectstatic` so I know all the static files are in the correct directory.

My `static` and `media` folders both live under the `myproject` folder, as well as `settings.py` and the main `urls.py`.

Comment: For me this works for `STATIC_URL='/static/'`, but not `/site_media/static/`. Even if I adjust `urls.py` accordingly, Django would not serve the files from this address. However, if I change one character in `STATIC_URL`, the particular files can be retrieved just fine --- though, of course, HTML files do not reference them correctly any longer. Yet changing `/site_media/static/` to `/static/` somehow makes it work. Not sure why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the (absolute) path to the directory which contains your static files to STATICFILES_DIRS in the settings. You don't neet to run collectstatic

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I figured django.views.static.serve would solve the problem in my urls.py.

Comment: Got it working! I fiddled around with STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS and got it to work with runserver; I'll update my question.

Comment: In the future, or when your project matures, you should serve your static files from an S3 Bucket or what not -- not through your application server ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working so that static files can be loaded via runserver and deploying to heroku also works.

Things I changed:

`settings.py`: Didn't change anything here, instead I will override some settings in my local_settings.py file.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

`local_settings.py`:
Added the following:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
)
```

This allows heroku to serve up your static files as well as runserver for development. It's also worth re-mentioning that I needed the extra static url patterns added to the end of my urls.py to get serving up static media in heroku.

Answer (score -1):

This is expected. Django doesn't serve static files. Heroku (apparently) does.

To serve files locally, you need to add a route in `urls.py` to serve the files.

Comment: I did at the end of my urls.py as posted.